# How to get children of terms in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a few levels of terms in term store. I wanted to be able to create the whole tree of terms using a single query

The following request doesn't return terms with their children:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/termStore/groups/{groupId}/sets/{setId}/terms?$expand=children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/termStore/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/sets/%7BsetId%7D/terms?$expand=children)

What is wrong with it?
I was able to get children for the single term by its id but not for the whole set of terms

Comment: Does it return any error or is expand simply ignored and children property is not populated?

Comment: It doesn't return the property, no errors